# Most Used Graphics Design Software?

Tags: android, graphics

quick question. I'm very new to Android development, and I'm even newer to the whole graphics design game. My question is, does anyone know what the majority of developers use to create all the graphics found in Android apps? Multiple programs? Just one that usually rises to the top? Thanks!

Comment: It's close but I think this question is worded just enough to make it non opinion based one.

Comment: this is what i use, this http://www.blender.org/ and photoshop

Comment: this too http://www.gimp.org/ we use this too, blender and this are free, theyre good

Comment: Many use Inkscape and Gimp. They're both open source and free.

Answer (score 0):

Photoshop is your answer, I personnaly don't create designs for apps, there is a designer for that, and he uses photoshop, and I know there is a way to make PS generate your 5 format of every icon (from LDPI to XXHDPI), try to make a google research